# SAML2 Protocol with my ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, saml, saml-2.0

I am planning to integrate an external authentication service based out of SAML 2.0 Protocol(SAML2P) with my ASP.NET Application, on .NET 4.5.2. I came to realize that .NET 4.5.2 supports SAML tokens but NOT saml2.0 protocol. Please advice to me achieve this ? Is there any way to do this in .NET 4.5.XX or any reliable open source libraries which are actively supporting this? Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

The Kentor.AuthServices open source library is a reliable SAML2 protocol implementation. It has over 45.000 downloads and is widely used. Choose between Kentor.AuthServices.HttpModule if you prefer an http module, Kentor.AuthServices.Mvc for a simple implementation in MVC projects or Kentor.AuthServices.Owin for a owin/katana middleware to use with ASP.NET Identity.

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of the library. Setting this to community wiki to not get any rep for the answer.*

Comment: Thanks Andres for your reply. I am planning to test with a SAML2 endpoint on AzureActiveDirectory. Everything went fine, Even I can see the SAMLRESPONSE with claims(attributes) in it. But I am getting a certificate error like "n exception of type 'Kentor.AuthServices.Exceptions.InvalidSignatureException' occurred in Kentor.AuthServices.dll" . Could you please help me on this?

Comment: That's another question. Please open a new question here at Stack Overflow or file a question in the github issue tracker for AuthServices.